# How to set timeout for WebSocket.ReceiveAsync

Tags: websocket

It seems WebSocket.ReceiveAsync waits potentially forever for data. Is there a way to set an inactivity timeout? Below is conceptually how the code would look:

```
public async Task DoListening(AspNetWebSocketContext context)
{
    WebSocketReceiveResult receiveResult = await socket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(receiveBuffer), CancellationToken.None);
    if (inactivity timeout ocurred)
    {
        DoInactivityAction();
    }
    else
    {
        DoReceiveAction();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom [cancellation token with timeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh139115(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public async Task DoListening(AspNetWebSocketContext context)
{
    var timeOut = new CancellationTokenSource(500).Token;
    WebSocketReceiveResult receiveResult;
    try
    {
        receiveResult = await socket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(receiveBuffer), timeOut );
        DoReceiveAction();
    }
    catch(OperationCancelledException)
    {
        DoInactivityAction();
    }
}
```

Untested code.

Comment: Ah, I was looking at the CancellationToken, not CancellationTokenSource. Thanks!

Comment: This throws TaskCanceledException and puts the socket into the aborted state, after that the socket cannot be used again, it will throw exceptions if you try. You can't retry without creating a whole new WebSocket

Comment: This does not work at all, no exception is thrown and the socket is aborted if/when future data is actually sent